# How to check connection in Odoo 8 API web service

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-8

May be this question has been discussed in some websites. But when I googling I found nothing. 
I am making connection to Odoo API web service from this docs https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html.
I have try this code to check whether connection is success or not.
I try this code by running in a browser (not in Android).

```
require_once('ripcord-master/ripcord.php');

$url = "http://100.100.1.148:8069"; //port odoo 8069, bukan postgresql 5432
$db = "UAT_DISTRICT";
$username = "openpg";
$password = "serving";

$info = ripcord::client('https://demo.odoo.com/start')->start();
$cekconn = list($url, $db, $username, $password) = array($info['host'], $info['database'], $info['user'], $info['password']);
if ($cekconn){
    echo "Connection success";
}
```

But why the `$cekconn` always returns true, so while I make the wrong user, the browser still shows "Connection success".

Anyone knows how to check that connection? Your answer is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in this part:

$info = ripcord::client('https://demo.odoo.com/start')->start();

you will get "https://demo.odoo.com" parameters to access its API (url,db,username,password), which will be used in $cekconn.

that's why it always working even with wrong user

add below line at the end of your code to know what I am talking about

print_r($info);